# Django: ограничить методы вьюсета

Tags: python, django, api

Для комментов нужны только GET и POST запросы, сейчас доступны все, и DELETE, и PUT и PATCH. Т.е. автор сейчас может менять и удалять свои комментарии, как можно ограничить методы вьюсета?

```
class CommentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsAuthorOrReadOnly]

    def _get_post(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Post, pk=self.kwargs.get('post_id'))

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self._get_post().comments.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user, post=self._get_post())
```